# Creating a cv::Mat image from a 3d array

Tags: c++, opencv, multidimensional-array, constructor, mat

Suppose I have an array

```
uint8_t img[1000][1200][3]
```

where the first 2 dimensions represent the size of the image (height, width),
and the third one the channels (BGR).
E.g.

```
img[200][100][1]
```

gives the value of the Green pixel with coordinates (200, 100).

How can I convert this array to a cv::Mat image?
I tried

```
cv::Mat my_image(1000, 1200, CV_8UC3, img);
```

but I am not sure if the result I am getting is correct. Any hints?

Comment: Do you know the content of `img`? Why not just use `imshow` and see the result?

Comment: what you tried is basically correct (comma before the CV_8UC3!), but may need a cast, *if* the compiler complains. why do you doubt the result's correctness? at most the color channels are the wrong way around, which you can fix with cvtColor. OpenCV expects BGR order, not RGB order.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in cpp, but the idea is following:

```
uint8_t img[1000][1200][3];
uint8_t *p = img;
//Consturctor takes a pointer to image data, possibly you will need to swap height and width. 
cv::Mat my_image(1000, 1200 CV_8UC3, (void*)p);
```

Comment: that solution is functionally identical to the question's code, apart from the casting.